# Оформление input type=file

Tags: html, javascript

Нужно сделать кнопку выбора картинки как в vk.com
Т.Е. Окно выбора файла по клику на div или button, и если файл выбран то отправка формы.
Пока нарыл только это http://habrahabr.ru/post/171743/#comment_5959055
**Уточнение** 
Сделал всё, через iframe. Всё работает и загружается на мой серв. Не получилось сделать красивый input type=file, пока что он выглядит как стандартный, выбор файла затем отправка формы по нажитию на input type=submit
Хочу что бы была одна кнопка загрузить файл и при выборе файла  форма отправлялась

Comment: звучит как заказ на фриланс-сайте

Comment: Уточните что сделали сами и что не получилось ? отправка файлов возможна в новых браузерах через ajax, в старых через iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если тебе нужно оформить кнопку, то

```
input[type="file"]{
z-index: 2;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
display: block;
}
```

а под неё размести блок с оформленной кнопкой того же размера